# Add optional parameter to button_click function

Tags: c#

I want to add an optional parameter to my button_click function so i can insert additional info by calling it from another function.

Here is the code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, string bla = "")
    {
        if (bla.Length > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(bla);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hi!");
        }
    }
    private void button1_trigger()
    {
        button1_Click(null, null, "hi");
    }
```

The error i'm getting from visual studio 2012
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it looks like your code should work (the last parameter is optional, so the "button1_Click" should still match the delegate), it does not due to a limitation in the C# compiler.  Namely, the compiler cannot match a method to a delegate, where the method has overloads, or optional parameters.  (This is with good reason -- it would be more complicated that you might think to handle these cases gracefully. Eric Lippert has written about this topic on his blog.)

I would just add another function that works with both cases, and call that one from the handler:

```
private void trigger(object sender, EventArgs e, string bla = "")
{
    if (bla.Length > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(bla);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hi!");
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    trigger(sender, e);
}

private void button1_trigger()
{
    trigger(null, null, "hi");
}
```

**Edit**

So, if you don't want to add an extra function for whatever reason, then you could use a lambda to add the handler:

```
this.button1.Click += (sender, args) => this.button1_Click(sender, args);
```

The resulting compiled code will actually be very similar (I believe the C# compiler will add another member function for the anonymous delegate), but this syntax is more compact, for sure.

Comment: It will throw a `NullReferenceException` on button click. No?

Comment: This is an 'dirty' workaround i don't want to make an additional function just to trigger the button function. Thanks for answering, im hoping for an other (less dirty) solution to this.

Comment: @Ismail I edited with an alternate that does not require the extra function.

Comment: @Ismail This isn't really "dirty". A control event should only handle getting the information required for being able to kick off a process. The example shows passing a sender and args, but you can always omit those. Sorry if I am stepping on your answer's toes McGarnagle.

Comment: Ismail on the contrary; attempting to shoe-horn an event handler into a role event handlers aren't designed for is **extra dirty**.  Do what you would do in any situation where you need to reuse the same  bit of code in more than one context: separate it out into a clean function with a sensible name. Favour expressive code over concise code.

Comment: @McGarnagle
The second solution works halfway, i'm getting an error: http://prntscr.com/53x1bf

Comment: @codesparkle 
I am using an keyboard listener that listens to keys that have an relation with buttons and triggers that button event/function. Thats the reason of the reuse.